# Data Migration In MVC3 (Using EF.4.3)

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I am doing data-migration for my project. But I have one question, for example:
I have Book table with following fields:

```
ID  Name   Color

1   Java    red

2   MVC     blue

3   .Net    blue
```

I tried to change the name of field from "Color" to "BookColor" using Code First tech. But after migration the table looked like this:

```
ID  Name   BookColor

1   Java    null

2   MVC     null

3   .Net    null
```

I lost my field values. How can I make sure that all value are transfered?

I'm using Entity Framework with MVC3

**EDIT** This  is  my DBMigration Class:

```
public partial class AddCreative : DbMigration
{

    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("Authors", "Names", c => c.String(maxLength: 4000));
        DropColumn("Authors", "Name");
    }


    public override void Down()
    {
        AddColumn("Authors", "Name", c => c.String(maxLength: 4000));
        DropColumn("Authors", "Names");
    }
}
```

I  have changed `Name` to `Names`  after changing (I lost my data in name field).

Comment: Can we see what you're `DbMigration` class looks like now?

Comment: This  is  My  DBMigration Class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had no problems using the following:

First, setup the migrations:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
PM> Add-Migration RenameBookColorColumn
```

Then we setup the migrations class to perform the rename:

```
public class RenameBookColorColumn : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        this.RenameColumn("Books", "Color", "BookColor");
    }
    public override void Down()
    {
        this.RenameColumn("Books", "BookColor", "Color");
    }
}
```

Next, make a call to `Update-Database` so we can perform the changes:

```
PM> Update-Database -Verbose
Using NuGet project 'Example'.
Using StartUp project 'ExampleTest'.
Target database is: 'ExampleContext' (DataSource: .\SQLEXPRESS, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention).
Applying explicit migrations: [201207051400010_RenameBookColorColumn].
Applying explicit migration: 201207051400010_RenameBookColorColumn.
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'Books.Color', @newname = N'BookColor',
@objtype = N'COLUMN' [Inserting migration history record]
```

And voila, it's renamed and the data is retained.

Comment: thanks -I have  tried  with  your code. - I am  getting this error -"Direct column renaming is not supported by SQL Server Compact. To rename a column in SQL Server Compact, you will need to recreate it."

Comment: There's your answer right there, you're going to need to either recreate the database our use sql express/ server.

Comment: But  if  i  ll  recreate  i  ll  lost  my  data  again  thats  thing  i  don't want

Comment: @Kaps: Understood, but you're working with a server that doesn't support migration. So you either need to move to a SQL Express/SQL Server or consider data loss a part of the process.

Comment: i  can't to move SQL Express/SQL ... because my client want only  compact server..  so  it  seems  we  don't  have any  solution for  this problam.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around the limitation by using the following code.

```
public partial class AddCreative : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("Authors", "Names", c => c.String(maxLength: 4000));
        Sql("UPDATE [Authors] SET [Names] = [Name]");
        DropColumn("Authors", "Name");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AddColumn("Authors", "Name", c => c.String(maxLength: 4000));
        Sql("UPDATE [Authors] SET [Name] = [Names]");
        DropColumn("Authors", "Names");
    }
}
```